# My code is not updating in the frontend

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created one content type template few days before

```
page--classroom_course.tpl.php
```

Now I'm trying to modify my code in that page but my changes are not showing in front end. Even I cleared cache everything but still the issue is same.

After that I removed that file and I again checked but it's not showing any error instead of that same output is showing.

I don't know how that is taking.

Comment: page--classroom-course.tpl.php change the name of the file like this.

Comment: no changes, still that page is showing.

Comment: Try with node--classroom-course.tpl.php

Comment: Do u have several copies of your site? Perhaps ur in the wrong server?

Comment: Are u in the correct theme folder? Which theme is enabled?

Comment: @jawaharj Clear Cache after placing the file :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the internal path of your page ? (not path alias).
Based on the internal path, you can find out how to create the correct template.
Or even better:
This is the best solution and the most precise:

In the theme folder, you can modify template.php and implement the following hook:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // If you have devel installed; if not, user var_dump or enable devel.
  kpr($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
  die();
}
```

Navigate to your page, after clear cache and you should see the theme hook suggestions and based on those, you can create your template.

E.q. If one of the suggestions is something like "page__page_name", then your template name will be "page--page-name.tpl.php".